# How to pass queryset from one view to another in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have searched for this but none of the solutions seem to work especially sessions.
I have a queryset and i have appended it to a list of tuples such that it looks like this:
[(a,b,c),(d,e,f), ...]

I want to pass that to another view. How do I achieve this?

Here is a code snippet:

views.py

```
  def  view1(request):
     job_details.append((job, recruiter, salary))


  def view2(request):
     #I want to access the queryset(job_details) here
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what your trying to do, but you could `POST` the data to your view either via a HTML form or via JavaScript using AJAX. [Here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html) is generally a good start to do it with JavaScript.

Comment: can you provide a small example in code pls?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source code of [Django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) you will find that it encodes a user-specified queryset as the GET part of the URL.

Or, it's possible that you just want to use Django-filter.

Comment: can you provide a small example in code pls?

Comment: Not easily. If you want to roll your own you redirect to an URL with GET parameters, fetch them in the next view ( from request.GET), and build the corresponding queryset (`qs.filter(**dict)` syntax). I mostly use django-filter. Looked at the source once to see how it performed its magic.

Comment: but apparently, you cannot pass a queryset to a url, right?

Comment: I didnt want to redirect to a new url. It is as if I display one result on the hompage, then the user clicks on 'View More' and then he gets all the results pre computed but it is handled by another view

Comment: i dont want to repeat the codes for the first view in the second view but rather wants to use the produced results from the first view

Comment: Well, you can redirect to the same URL with new GET parameters. A view takes something from a user, generates something from the user, and exits, usually by redirecting. You cannot pass anything from the user to a view, other than through its URL, hence the need to encode it as GET parameters.

Comment: how do I pass it to the url?

Comment: are you understanding what im tryna doing?